# Why can’t I print to my printer using Canon TS6000 series – CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.13-2 driver?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

This is a new printer for me on my Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.  After searching for ways to install, I added this printer via the  http://localhost:631/ website.  I have “added” this printer twice – one with the above driver, and one with Canon TS6200 series Ver 5.70 (en).  I can print using the latter driver, but cannot using the “Gutenprint” driver: Canon TS6000 series – CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.13-2 driver.  Is there another version that might work?

Answer (score 0):

I have been informed from the maintainer of the Canon gutenprint project that this is not the correct driver for my printer and that he expects "to be able to find time to work on support for some of the newer TS series by April."